# Is it posible to insert a UITextView (or other UIKit view) into an augmented reality SCNScene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, augmented-reality, scenekit

Weird crazy question I know. My current setup is a SCNScene with a camera controlled by the device's gyroscope. I'm able to add and light normal nodes, however I would like to add 2D UIView objects into the scene like UITextViews or maybe some buttons. The views would need to be inside the scene and thus become no longer visible if the camera moves away from them.

Firstly, is this even possible? Or would this be way more difficult to implement than rebuilding an editable textview as a node? Could this be achieved by categories or...?

Comment: Are you trying to interact what the text view or simply display text on a flat surface?

Comment: I would be interacting with the text view with a Bluetooth keyboard, so I couldn't just attach an image of my text to a square @DavidRönnqvist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just talked to the scenekit people here at WWDC. He said that as of now it is completly impossible to do it in a nice, functional way. The only options he offered as a possible solution is to create the UIView element somewhere off screen or behind the scene and continuously take screenshots of the object and apply those images as a texture to a SCNNode. He also pointed out the performance will be very poor with this because taking screenshots is heavy and you can't get going very quick with it. So I guess this is a no-go until UIView adds support because, according to the engineer, it's impossible to implement this because of a UIView limitation and not a SceneKit one.